# Flutter expand animation to half screen not changing routes

Tags: flutter, dart

guys i see this cool expanding animation in gallery.flutter.dev i was trying to see the code how to produce it in the first screen and the second one but i cannot find any clue because the code is too complex , do you guys know how to achieve something like this ? i don't think it use hero animation because it does not change any screen routes.

the first screen i want is from this expanding tile like
[this website](https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/reply)
[image]
[image]

and the second one is from expanding button to full screen like [this website](https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/shrine)

[image]
[image]